# Dell EqualLogic PS6010E Network Setup

Tags: storage-area-network, dell-equallogic

We recently got a PS6010E and going through setup, I put in all the IP info we are planning on using, and when I get to the part where it says to go to http://[group-ip-addr], I am unable to connect. Also tried SSH and Telnet. Looking at the switch, it looks like the MAC is not showing up on the interface, even though the link is up. Haven't had any luck looking through settings that may change this. Any ideas?